# Disabling next & previous in Spotify app

Tags: spotify

Is there any way to disable the next/previous button in the Spotify apps api, like SoundDrop was able to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you play a track without a context, or play a track with a context containing only one track, the playback controls are disabled.

SoundDrop takes the first approach — it only plays a single track at a time with no context, and manually plays the next track when it's time.

Comment: How can this be accomplished with the new apps api (1.18.0 - https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/index.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this issue.

Setting the context to a context with only one track wasn't the entire solution, since I had to run an undocumented function on the playlist too.

But take a look at my solution here:

[Disable next previous buttons in spotify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293430/disable-next-previous-buttons-in-spotify)