# Disable next previous buttons in spotify

Tags: spotify

I want to be able to disable the Next and the previous buttons in spotify.
I know it's possible because the soundrop app has managed to do it.

I have searched around a bit, and from my understanding, I am supposed to play a track with the context as null or a context containing only 1 track. I have been testing around with all the possible solutions I can think of, but none of them seems to work. Most of them actually result in the track being played with context as null, but the Next/Previous buttons are always enabled.

If I press the next button, the player ends up not playing any track, and both buttons are disabled...

Below is the code from my test application.

```
var sp = getSpotifyApi(1);
var models = sp.require('sp://import/scripts/api/models');
var views = sp.require('sp://import/scripts/api/views');

models.player.observe(models.EVENT.CHANGE, function (o) {
    console.log(['Player Change', o, models.player.context]);
})

$('#play1').click(function () {
    models.Track.fromURI("spotify:track:5A1fNC7Fdb0yyh3UA6T1ef", function (track) {
        console.log(["play1", track.name]);
        models.player.play(track, null);
    });
});

$('#play2').click(function () {
    models.Track.fromURI("spotify:track:5A1fNC7Fdb0yyh3UA6T1ef", function (track) {
        console.log(["play2", track.name]);
        var p = new views.Player();
        p.play(track, null);
    });
});

$('#play3').click(function () {
    models.Track.fromURI("spotify:track:5A1fNC7Fdb0yyh3UA6T1ef", function (track) {
        console.log(["play3", track.name]);
        var pl = new models.Playlist();
        pl.add(track);
        models.player.play(track, pl);
    });
});

$('#play4').click(function () {
    console.log(["play4"]);
    models.player.play("spotify:track:5A1fNC7Fdb0yyh3UA6T1ef", null);
});

$('#play5').click(function () {
    models.Track.fromURI("spotify:track:5A1fNC7Fdb0yyh3UA6T1ef", function (track) {
        models.player.playTrack(track);
    });
});

$('#play6').click(function () {
    models.Track.fromURI("spotify:track:5A1fNC7Fdb0yyh3UA6T1ef", function (track) {
        console.log(["play6", track.name]);
        var pl = new models.Playlist();
        pl.add(track);
        models.player.playTrackWithContext(track, pl, 0);
    });
});

$('#play7').click(function () {
    var l = new models.Link("spotify:track:5A1fNC7Fdb0yyh3UA6T1ef");
    sp.trackPlayer.setContextCanSkipNext(l, false);
    console.log(["play7", models.player, sp.trackPlayer],l);
    models.player.play(l, null);
});
```

Result from #play1:

```
["play1", "Jag är här nu"]
["Player Change", Object, null]
```

Result from #play2:

```
["play2", "Jag är här nu"]
["Player Change", Object, null]
```

Result from #play3:

```
["play3", "Jag är här nu"]
["Player Change", Object, "spotify:internal:temp_playlist:spotify:app:myapplication@687556942764"]
```

Result from #play4:

```
["play4"]
["Player Change", Object, null]
```

Result from #play5:

```
["play5", "Jag är här nu"]
["Player Change", Object, null]
```

Result from #play6:

```
["play6", "Jag är här nu"]
["Player Change", Object, "spotify:internal:temp_playlist:spotify:app:myapplication@217702072872"]
```

Result from #play7:

```
sp.trackPlayer.setContextCanSkipNext(l, false);
```

The above line generates an exception with the message "Failed to convert param 0 to link"

Thanks in advance

Comment: No one has any ideas? I've seen this question a few times before on stackoverflow, but none of them get any real answers either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've after some work now, found out how to do this.

```
models.Track.fromURI("spotify:track:5A1fNC7Fdb0yyh3UA6T1ef", function (track) {
    var pl = new models.Playlist();
    sp.trackPlayer.setContextCanSkipPrev(pl.uri, false);
    sp.trackPlayer.setContextCanSkipNext(pl.uri, false);
    pl.add(track);
    models.player.play(track, pl);
});
```

Hope this helps anyone else out there attempting to resolve this issue and getting stuck in the talk about playing a track with an empty context...

Comment: Any idea how to accomplish this with the new app framework api (1.18.0 - https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/index.html)? The magic methods 'setContextCanSkip*' along with the entire sp global are no more.